# In “Speckles: The Tarbosaurus”, Speckles’ mate Blue Eyes sustained an injury to her left leg, but she healed

Tags: dinosaurs, dino-king

In “[Speckles: The Tarbosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speckles:_The_Tarbosaurus)” (2012), Speckles’ mate Blue Eyes sustained an injury to her left leg, but she healed.

Later, however, the same leg was reinjured when she had a rock falling on it. Did it heal this time?

Comment: R.I.P Blue Eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. Blue Eyes is seen in a later scene favouring her injured leg and suffering from exhaustion as a result. She collapses, and as she lies dying a swarm of velociraptors gather around.

Speckles makes an attempt to scare them off, but eventually decides to leave after her death.

Comment: Again, R.I.P Blue Eyes.

Comment: @LouisHolmes - She went to a variety of better places